# Update two version of owl file in fuseki

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology, fuseki

I have some trouble about uploading files on fuseki. 
If I have an owl file (`ontov1.owl`)   and I uploaded it in `my_dataset` on fuseki. Then I have a new version of the same owl file ( `ontov2.owl` ) , maybe I added some triples and deleted others in this new version. Is it possible to update the graph in `my_dataset` from the `ontov1.owl` to the `ontov2.owl` in order that changes between the first and second version is considered ?

Comment: You have to compute the diff and apply it via SPARQL update. RDF Delta is an interesting project to handle changsets: https://afs.github.io/rdf-delta/

Comment: computing the diff for RDF with no blank nodes is trivial. once you have blank nodes, graph isomorphism is needed. If you have OWL it's likely that you have blank nodes once you use complex class expressions. Here indeed you could compute some diff on the axiom level.

Comment: A higher level notion of diff may be useful. Look for e.g. class definitions that have changed. Delete the old in entirety, add the new one. This may well be more triples in the "diff".